# Does Essence Burn include the explosion damage from Exploding Palm?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

The new patch buffed Exploding Palm in a big way.  You hit a monster with it, it starts bleeding.  Kill it while the bleed is active, it explodes for 50% of it's maximum health.  Needless to say, that's a LOT of damage to be dealing out from a single skill.  Use it on two or three monsters in the same pack, and you can often cause a chain reaction that takes out the rest of the pack.

Now, the last rune for Exploding Palm is Essence Burn.  The rune text is:

> Instead of bleeding, the enemy will burn for X% weapon damage as Fire over Y seconds.  If the enemy dies while burning, it explodes causing all nearby enemies to burn for Z% weapon damage as Fire over N seconds.  This effect can happen multiple times.

Based on usage, I get the exploding effect on other multiple enemies, but I can't seem to figure out if they take the extra 50% explosion damage *on top* of the burning effect.  If they do, Essence Burn is seriously silly in how you can just apply it to one, and watch the explosions happen.

Comment: I think this wouldn't be hard to test. All you have to do is kill a mob using an extremely weak weapon or have your follower do so. Essence Burn's damage will do % weapon damage based off of your weapon. If you don't see surrounding mobs take a chunk of damage when the first mob explodes, then the 50% hp-to-damage explosion is not retained.  From what I read, the monk community thinks it does not get retained otherwise everyone would be using Essence Burn for farming, even at higher Torment levels.

Answer (score 1):

According the [this thread](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/8796570812) on Diablo's forums, it does not retain the exploding damage. [This thread](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/7593580561) might be of interest to you if you wanna run a EP build.

Comment: The threads are somewhat out of date; for example the explosion is no longer reflected (or I'd murder myself whenever one of them died with reflect up).  That said, I do think they are correct in that it doesn't keep the explosion.

Comment: Check the latest posts which brings some more up to date informations. Yes the start of the threads are outdated.

Comment: The latest posts from those threads is from May and August last year.  That's still out of date, since they're from prior to patch 2.01.

Comment: It seems I can't read today :)